# How to use price thousand separator in woocommerce Admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem displaying numbers on the WooCommerce admin page.
I want to use woocommerce price thousand separator for show sepraret symbol in admin panel, such as product edit page and etc.
I checked thousand separator in woocommerce setting, but its only for backend site.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your query. price with thousand separator is defined by wc_get_price_thousand_separator() function.